# Correct way to design around Windows UAC limitations?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, installation, uac

I found out an application I wrote does not work properly under Windows Vista/7 if UAC is enabled at any level, because it writes files to the install directory of the program, defaults to "C:\Program Files\MyProgram." If UAC is disabled (or on any other version of Windows) it works properly - I read that UAC denies applications write access to the Program Files directory by default.

My question is, well, how should I write my application so that it can be used without any "rights" needed at all. I don't want users to have to run it with elevated privileges or as administrator. I just want it to work. Are there certain directories that any app has write access to under UAC where it might be better to write my files? They are mostly config files that are dynamically created/destroyed/updated.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I wouldn't call UAC restrictions "limitations" on your application. Technically they are, but more or less it just guides you into not doing something you shouldn't ever do in the first place

Comment: "shouldn't ever do" - why not?

Comment: Why on Earth would you ever want to write configuration data to Program Files? That's the installation directory. That's where the executables and the libraries go. Data doesn't go there...

Comment: @Jim - Your app was broken in many other scenarios, like non-admin users.  Vista pushes the non-admin case to be more of a default.

If non-admins could write to program files, a nonprivileged user could drop any number of trojan programs there and get an admin to run them, owning the box.

Comment: Users would never think to backup data in that location

Comment: AppData sounds like the right solution. Perhaps it sounds obvious to some, but it didn't seem that obvious to me. The files are not meant for users, they are specifically for the program to store settings. I figured what better place than where the application exists. Looks like I was wrong. I will change my method.

Comment: It comes from the long security tradition of Unix. On Unix, you have a folder with the binaries, another with configuration files another with user files and another with temporal files. That should be all you need to use for normal usage. If you are writing to the binaries folder, it's assumed you are doing something "bad". From what you are saying, you have your design wrong. The config files should be on the AppData folder.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sounded harsh at all Jim. I know it's not your fault. Things were done like this for a long time. It's just that the past few years there has been a big push to get developers to stop doing this because it's wrong, and it's really important that developers follow. I'm glad you are willing to change once you discovered that it wasn't the right thing to do.

Comment: For what it's worth, program files has been the wrong place to store config information on windows for one and a half decades, now.  (Yes, since Windows 95.)  It's worth your time to do some due diligence and read up a little on the OS that you're making a living off of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per-user application specific data should be written in the AppData folder.

You should use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(VS.85).aspx) with FOLDERID_LocalAppData.

In managed code, you should use [System.Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) with System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData.

Comment: If you use the .NET configuration abilities (`System.Configuration` namespace, these are the .settings files in a C# project), your data will be placed in the proper location and you'll have very elegant ways to access and update it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are specific locations.  Consider [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756940.aspx) as a first reference.  It mentions the locations:

- `CSIDL_APPDATA`
- `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`
- `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`

In native code, the method [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28VS.85%29.aspx) should prove useful.

In managed code you can use [`Environment.GetFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx).  If you're in a specific application framework, such as windows forms, you can get even easier access via direct properties, such as [`Application.LocalUserAppDataPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.localuserappdatapath.aspx) (which is my personal favorite technique).  The framework path will include app-specific qualifiers on the path it returns to distinguish between (e.g.) different versions of your app.